# linux could't copy files to the server access denied

Tags: linux, tomcat

I want to copy a war file to my tomcat server. the server is linux

First of all, i totally can do this:

```
ssh dev@myserver
```

then i put my password, **it works**
then i can do this:

```
cd /bla/bla/tomcat/webapps
```

now i want to copy the war, i do this:

```
scp myFile.war dev@myserver:/bla/bla/tomcat/webapps/myFile.war
```

i put the password,
but then i get this error message:

```
scp: /bla/bla/tomcat/webapps/myFile.war: Permission denied
```

what am i doing wrong please?

sidenote, my operation system is mac os

**update** how can I use sudo to do the copy?

Comment: does `dev` user have permission to write in `/bla/bla/tomcat/webapps/` ?

Comment: Rewording Manos comment: just doing a "cd /somewhere" doesn't tell if you have WRITE access to that place. Try something like "touch /somewhere/blub" which creates a file in that directory... besides: this is not really a programming question; it might fit better to superuser.com for example.

Comment: @ManosNikolaidis i really don't know, but before i ask my manager, i would like to know if i am doing the commands correctly. if yes, then i can tell her that my user is not authorized

Comment: @Jägermeister i will try to touch and create a test txt file. i will update you

Comment: after doing `ssh` and `cd` do a `ls -l`. You will see on the left the permissions of each file and who owns it. If you see something like `drwxr-xr-x   9 root root` then you can't write there

Comment: try scp without the file given on the second parameter:  `scp myFile.war dev@myserver:/bla/bla/tomcat/webapps/`

Comment: @sinclair i already tried, the same error message

Comment: i was told to use sudo, anybody knows how to use it with the scp please?

Comment: @Jägermeister kindly check my new comments and my updated question

Comment: @ManosNikolaidis kindly check my new comments and my updated question

Comment: If root access at `myserver` is required and you know the password use it for scp e.g. `scp myFile.war root@myserver`. I agree with @Jägermeister that this question is for serverfault.com  or superuser.com

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli The point of sudo is to allow a non-root user to run commands as "root". But this won't help you: the point is that you need ROOT permission on the REMOTE system in order to create the file there. But sudo gives you ROOT on the LOCAL system. So, there are only two options: you make sure that "dev" has write permissions in that directory on the remote system, or you do a "scp root@" ... which requires you to know the root password on the REMOTE system.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
scp myFile.war root@myserver:/bla/bla/tomcat/webapps/myFile.war
```

Comment: And then Tomcat will be able to access files that were created by root? Not sure if that is really the way to handle things; especially as it requires the developer to have root permissions on that system.

Comment: but the war was copied, where is the problem?

Comment: I told you exactly what the two potential problems are. I am not saying that it doesn't work; I am merely pointing out the things that can go wrong when creating files using root permissions. Depending on ones setup, tomcat might **not** be running with root permissions ...

Comment: @Jägermeister the app is working, the only thing that i had to do is to shutdown tomcat and restarted it again